# MySQL : Using MIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

Table have the following data
Each same ID has the same datetime.

```
ID |     sendtime  |  gcm  | type
1, 2010-07-14 12:12:12, 1111111,  a
1, 2010-07-14 12:12:12, 2222222,  b
1, 2010-07-14 12:12:12, 3333333,  c
2, 2010-07-10 11:11:11, 4444444,  d
2, 2010-07-10 11:11:11, 5555555,  c
3, 2010-07-15 13:13:13, 6666666,  b
4, 2010-07-14 14:14:14, 7777777,  a
```

**I want to get values following**

```
ID |     sendtime  |  gcm  | type
2, 2010-07-10 11:11:11, 4444444,  d
2, 2010-07-10 11:11:11, 5555555,  c
```

Result means to get all rows having same ID and COUNT(*) > 1 and MIN(datetime).

I tried the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM USER a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ID, MIN(sendtime)
      FROM USER
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) b
     ON a.ID = b.ID;
```

But result is

```
1, 2010-07-14 12:12:12, 1111111,  a
1, 2010-07-14 12:12:12, 2222222,  b
1, 2010-07-14 12:12:12, 3333333,  c
2, 2010-07-10 11:11:11, 4444444,  d
2, 2010-07-10 11:11:11, 5555555,  c
```

How to get right values?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to express your logic:

```
select u.*
from user u
where u.sendtime = (select min(u2.sendtime) from user u2 where u2.id = u.id
                   ) and
      (select count(*)
       from user u2
       where u2.id = u.id and u2.sendtime = u.sendtime
      ) >= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this work.

SELECT a.*
FROM USER a INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ID FROM USER
      GROUP BY ID
      HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      ORDER BY SENDTIME ASC LIMIT 1
     ) b
     ON a.ID = b.ID;

Comment: I don't see how this "works".  It returns one user that has a duplicate, which does not seem to be what your question is asking for.